# Biggest Number Function in C++

Tags: c++, function

```
void biggest_number() {
    float first_input;
    float big_num;
    float input;
    cout <<"\n You've chosen to Find out The Biggest Number. Type in number to compare\nType 0 if you want to stop the function.\nFirst number : ";

    cin >> first_input;
    first_input = big_num;
    //cout << first_input;

    while (1) {
        cin >> input;

        if (big_num < input) {
            input = big_num;
        }
        else if (input == 0) {
            cout << big_num;
            break;
        }
        else{
        }
    };
};
```

So I've written a function to find the biggest number. But whatever I put as an input, `big_num` always comes out as 0.

I've tried to use `cout <<first_input << big_num;` in order to find out where the function doesn't work. You can see from the comment. That part doesn't work and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: `big_num` is uninitialized. This sequence `cin >> first_input; first_input = big_num;` reads a value into `first_input` then immediately overwrites it with the uninitialized `big_num`. May want to rethink your logic.

Comment: Nitpick: you have two instances of `};` and the semi-colons are absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: *So I've written a function to find the biggest number.* -- FYI, this can be done in [one line of code](https://ideone.com/SSg8EC)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i didn't know about those libraries but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have the assignment `first_input = big_num;` reversed. It should be `big_num = first_input;`

Comment: it worked that way, but why?

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
float big_num;
```

You declare `big_num` but haven't assigned it a value, so `big_num` is uninitialized. So `big_num` can hold any value. Then, you assign `first_input` to equal `big_num`. So both `first_input` and `big_num` is holding random values.

It seems kind of strange to me that you input `first_input`, then immediately you assign `first_input` to equal `big_num`. I think that you meant the other way around.

```cpp
big_num = first_input;
```

Also:

```cpp
void biggest_number() {
    float first_input;
    float big_num;
    float input;
    cout <<"\n You've chosen to Find out The Biggest Number. Type in number to compare\nType 0 if you want to stop the function.\nFirst number : ";

    cin >> first_input;
    first_input = big_num;
    //cout << first_input;

    while (1) {
        cin >> input;

        if (big_num < input) {
            input = big_num;
        }
        else if (input == 0) {
            cout << big_num;
            break;
        }
        else{
        }
    }; // <-- here
}; // <-- and here
```

There is two unnecessary semicolons. You should remove it.

note: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is bad practice, so avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void biggest_number()
{
    float first_input;
    float big_num;
    float input;
    cout <<"\n You've chosen to Find out The Biggest Number. Type in number to compare\nType 0 if you want to stop the function.\nFirst number : ";

    cin >> first_input;
    big_num = first_input;
    cout << "Second number :";
    

    while (1) 
    {
        cin >> input;

        if (first_input < input) 
        {
            big_num = input;
            cout<< big_num << "  Is the big number" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (input == first_input)
        {
            cout << "Both inputs are same" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<< big_num << "Is the big number" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}




int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    biggest_number();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: avoid while loop.No need because you use break. I didn't catch the usage.

Answer (score 1):

See @justANewbie's answer about the actual problem (mixing up your `input` and `big_num` variables).

I just wanted to provide a more compact solution. It's not important that the code is short in this case, but you might learn some more convenient C++ coding tricks/styles from it. Additionally, it's sometimes easier to spot errors when the code is compact and has less branching.

This solution uses a common C++ pattern you might call "read while":

```cpp
#include <cmath> // for INFINITY
#include <iostream>

void biggest_number() {
    float biggest = -INFINITY;

    // while we can read a number and it's not zero
    for (float input; (std::cin >> input) && input != 0; ) {
        // keep track of biggest number found
        if (input > biggest) biggest = input;
    }

    std::cout << biggest;
}
```